# Adding two number variables returns NaN

Tags: javascript, variables, nan

Working on a simple game, using delta time for the first time.

Delta time (dt) is created in this function:

```
function main() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var dt = (now - lastTime) / 1000.00;

    update(dt);
    render();

    lastTime = now;
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};
```

gameTime (my second variable) is just created as a var.

```
var gameTime = 0;
```

The problem comes when I try to add dt to gameTime, here:

```
function update(dt){
    gameTime += dt;
};
```

this returns NaN, whatever I seem to do to it. I can display gameTime, and add to it using ++, and I can display dt (0.017 usually), but as soon as I add one to the other, I get NaN.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Declare `lastTime` variable `var lastTime = 0;` before use it

Answer (score 1):

Does your `lastTime` contain anything before running `main()` for the first time?

If not, then this code `var dt = (now - lastTime) / 1000.00;` can't work because `lastTime` is `undefined`

Comment: As an additional tip to the "questioner": Always apply 'use strict'; when programming in JavaScript. It will warn you of errors such as these.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you return you can see your result which is not NaN, basically you write it like this :

```
function update(dt)
{
return gameTime += dt;
};
```

Second of all,if you are not using this code in vanilla javascript and it's related to unity,  try to initiate your variables. like how you defined `var gameTime = 0;`, check other variables and initiate them.